# Как определить имя делегата вызвавшего метод?

Tags: c#, делегаты

Для определения имени вызывающего метода использую `stackTrace.GetFrame (0).GetMethod ().Name`

Но как определить имя делегата посредством которого вызывается метод ?

Ниже приведен псевдокод.
Представим что в вызываемых методах у меня нет возможности определить какая логика сработала кроме как получив имя делегата (d1 или d2) или его хеш.

```
public class A {
    public Action<int> d2;
    public Action<int> d1;
    public void Start () {                        
        d1 = fn1;   
        d2 = fn2;
        if(something)   {.... logic1 ... d1(1);}
        else            {.... logic2 ... d2(1);}
    }

    void fn1(int i){
        StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();   
        print ( stackTrace.GetFrame (1).GetMethod ().Name );
    }
    void fn2(int i){
        StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();   
        print ( stackTrace.GetFrame (1).GetMethod ().Name );
    }
}
```

Comment: добавь пример кода, в котором ты это хочешь определить, и что имеется ввиду под _именем_ делегата?

Comment: в данном виде ты хочешь получить на выводе `fn1`, `fn2` или `d1`, `d2`? Ага, увидел

Comment: а зачем в методе определять какая логика была до его вызова?